# Set timeout based on query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, settimeout

How to set up a timeout for some specific queries using Java or Hibernate. The problem I am facing is that some queries where I have to fetch large amount of data some times do not respond for longer periods resulting in an unresponsive application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate query has [setTimeout()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setTimeout%28int%29) method

```
Query query = session.createQuery(someQueryString);
query.setTimeout(theTimeOut);
```

Answer (score 1):

JPA **standard** property `javax.persistence.query.timeout` can also be provided as a "hint" to each query.

```
query.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", someTimeout);
```

Hence avoiding tying your code to one JPA provider or another.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate supports Transaction time outs:

```
    //set transaction timeout to 5 seconds at session
    Session sess = factory.openSession();
    sess.getTransaction().setTimeout(5);
```

You can also setup at [query level](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html).

```
Query q = sess.createQuery("from....")
          .setTimeOut(3);
```